# React/Mobx: How to pass single item from a mapped array into another component and retrieve only the item associated with the value clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, mobx

I have a API which is pushed into a store called PositionStore; as shown

```
const PositionStore = observable({
loading: false,
error: "",
items: [] as PositionInfo[],

LoadPosition() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.error = "";

    GetPositions()
    .then(action((json:any) => {
        this.items = json.items;
        console.log(json)
        this.loading = false;
    }))
    .catch(action((error: any) => {
        this.error = error.message;
        this.loading = false;
    }));
}
});
```

In my JobCard component, I am mapping the data in the PositionStore Array to display all cards with the relevant information, here is my AllJobCard.tsx

```
const AllJobCard = observer(() => {
return (
    <Row className={'JobCard_Row'}>
        {PositionStore.items.map((positions, id) => (
            <Card className={'AllJobCard'}>
                <Row className={'Header_Row'}>
                    <CardHeader
                        avatar={
                            <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={'avatar'}>
                                A
                            </Avatar>
                        }
                        title={positions.position_full_name}
                        subheader={positions.target_fill_date}
                    />
                    <JobDetails />
                </Row>
                <CardContent className="cardContentRow">
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                        <div>
                            {positions.equivalent_nato_rank} - {positions.rank}
                        </div>
                        <div> {positions.organisation_name} </div>
                        <div> {positions.location_name}</div>
                        <div> {positions.cap_badge} </div>
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions disableSpacing className={'actions'}>
                    <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
                        <FavoriteIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </CardActions>
            </Card>
        ))}
    </Row>
);
});
```

This looks like so...[image]

Inside each card, I have a button which onClick brings up a drawer, which will detail more information about the selected card, However I am unsure how to display the specific data which exists in a single card which has been mapped from the array into the more information drawer.

Have I explained myself well?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you can just store selected item (or its id) inside store, like that:

```
const store = observable({
  loading: false,
  error: "",
  selectedItemId: null,
  selectedItem: null,
  items: []
});
```

When mapping over items use `onClick` handler to set this value:

```
onClick={() => {
  store.selectedItem = item;
  // Or if you prefer store it by id
  store.selectedItemId = item.id;
}}
```

(Better make action for it in real code, I'm inlining it for this example)

Then check that it exists and show it:

```
    <div>
      {store.selectedItem && (
        <div>
          Selected item info:
          <h4>{store.selectedItem.name}</h4>
          <div>{store.selectedItem.description}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
```

If you store it by id then find it (or make computed) before showing:

```
  const selectedItem = store.items.find(
    (item) => item.id === store.selectedItemId
  );
```

I've made an example for you on Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions66475608-jh73w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. On the const List I am getting the error ;Type 'PositionInfo' is not assignable to type 'null'' when hovering over PositionStore.selectedItem = item and PostionStore.selectedItemId = item.id

Comment: Obviously you need to adapt types for your needs. For example, `selectedItem: null as PositionInfo | null` and so on